# htaccess issue with url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

This is my htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/index.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

This has successfully removed index.php but left ? before query string like

```
http://example.com/?type=1
```

How can I remove this '?' using htaccess

Also, how can I actually show above url as:

```
http://example.com/type/1
```

Comment: Now following is my .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^type/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?type=$1 [L]
```

**How it works**

The `RewriteRule ^type/([^/.]+)/?$` means that it's setting the URL of your path to `type/5*/` *= whatever number is put in there.

Then the information given in the new url would then pass it to the index page. (`index.php?type=$1 [L]`)

So for example, if you had type/1 it would forward that to index.php?type=1

I hope that this helps you and you now have a wider understanding of how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^type/([^/]*)$ /index.php?type=$1 [L]
```